# Diagnosing Bad OutputPaths: "The OutputPath property is not set for this project" (in the wonderful world of web deployment projects)

Tags: .net, web-deployment-project, deployment-project

Starting with the error:

> Error 81  The OutputPath property is
>   not set for this project.  Please
>   check to make sure that you have
>   specified a valid
>   Configuration/Platform combination. 
>   Configuration='Staging' 
>   Platform='AnyCPU' C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets  490 9   crm_deploy

We have a VS 2005 built website with a web deployment project. In this WDP there are two configurations, Staging and Production.

In the .sln for the whole website, we have two configurations with the same name, which are designed to trigger the corresponding deployment projects.

Production builds fine, but Staging returns the error above. I tried updating the .wdproj and .sln so that Staging matched production; I tried copying all the settings from Production to a new configuration (StagingX) by updating these same two files.

In each case, Production still works, but any new configurations I create produce the error above.

I've done a find across the whole project for the word Production and tried searching Googlespace and haven't found anything that explains the problem. WDPs are huge migraine creation devices. Any ideas? Thanks!

---

(I'll add files as requested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently a separate library without a Staging build can break it, even if the solution's Staging configuration is set to use the library's Debug build?

Oh well...